# Hiding a input text field that doesnt have an id

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so here is my question.

I have some code that I cannot access the file for so I want to use either Java script or Jquery to control it.

```
<li class="aaAttrty" id="aaAttrty_PRACSET">
<label>Practice Setting</label>
<select name="f46">
<option value="%null%" id="aaAttrTySelect_PRACSET_Null">Select One
</option><option value="PRIVATE_PRAC" 
id="aaAttrTySelect_PRACSET_PRIVATEPRAC">Private Practice (Solo)
</option><option value="ENDO_GRP_PRAC" 
id="aaAttrTySelect_PRACSET_ENDOGRPPRAC">Endodontic Group Practice
</option><option value="MULTI_GRP_PRAC" 
id="aaAttrTySelect_PRACSET_MULTIGRPPRAC">Multi-discipline Group Practice 
(Specialists and Generalists)
</option><option value="MILITARY" 
id="aaAttrTySelect_PRACSET_MILITARY">Military/Government Practice
</option><option value="DENT_FAC" id="aaAttrTySelect_PRACSET_DENTFAC">Dental 
School Faculty
</option><option value="INDPEN_CONT" 
id="aaAttrTySelect_PRACSET_INDPENCONT">Independent Contractor
</option><option value="NO_PRAC" id="aaAttrTySelect_PRACSET_NOPRAC">Not 
Currently in Practice
</option><option value="OTHER" id="aaAttrTySelect_PRACSET_OTHER">Other
</option></select>

<input type="text" name="f47" size="20" maxlength="4000" value="">
</li>
```

What I am trying to do is hide the input field unless the option of OTHER is selected.

I tried to use this but it isnt working and not sure why.

```
    $("#aaAttrty_PRACSET > ul > li > input[type=text]").hide();
    $("#aaAttrty_PRACSET > ul > li > input[value=OTHER]").click(function () 
    {
        if ($("#aaAttrty_PRACSET > ul > li > 
    input[value=OTHER]:checked").length > 0) {
            $("#aaAttrty_PRACSET > ul > li > input[type=text]").show();
        } else { $("#aaAttrty_PRACSET > ul > li > input[type=text]").hide(); 
    }
    });
```

I also tried Java Script Method and it actually broke the site all together which was weird.  This was my Java script attempt.

```
$(document).ready (function CheckOther(val){
var element=document.getElementById('#aaAttrty_PRACSET input');
if(val==='OTHER')
    element.style.display='block';
else  
   element.style.display='none';
 });
```

I would prefer the Jquery method so if anyone has any ideas let me know.  Here is one thing I cannot use and that is the name="xxxx"  because this changes as it is a dynamic form.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Kirk

Comment: There is no checkbox in your unordered list.

Comment: Your selector looks completely wrong for the example HTML you've included.

Comment: Do you only need to show/hide once, or each time the dropdown changes?

Comment: So in this issue here is the problem as the code below shows using the input[name=XX] however this is a dynamic value.   Because of that I am trying to choose based on what is wrapped inside of the <li> tag hence the ul>li>input portion.  If i could use the name+xx then I would have finished this project by now but I cannot so i am trying to figure out a different method to do what is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery selectors are a bit more complex than they need to be. Since we can't rely on the name attribute name (you say it always changes) so we can rely on the OTHER option tag ID and the li tag id

Also you should be using the `change` event for the `<select>` tag instead of a `click` event on the `<option>` tag. For example

```js
var $theInput = $("#aaAttrty_PRACSET > input:first");
$theInput.css("display", "none");

$("#aaAttrTySelect_PRACSET_OTHER").parent().on("change", function() {
  if (this.value === "OTHER") {
    $theInput.css("display", "block");
  } else {
    $theInput.css("display", "none");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="aaAttrty" id="aaAttrty_PRACSET">
  <label>Practice Setting</label>
  <select name="f46">
      <option value="%null%" id="aaAttrTySelect_PRACSET_Null">Select One</option>
      <option value="PRIVATE_PRAC"id="aaAttrTySelect_PRACSET_PRIVATEPRAC">Private Practice (Solo)</option>
      <option value="ENDO_GRP_PRAC"id="aaAttrTySelect_PRACSET_ENDOGRPPRAC">Endodontic Group Practice</option>
      <option value="MULTI_GRP_PRAC" id="aaAttrTySelect_PRACSET_MULTIGRPPRAC">Multi-discipline Group Practice(Specialists and Generalists)</option>
      <option value="MILITARY" id="aaAttrTySelect_PRACSET_MILITARY">Military/Government Practice</option>
      <option value="DENT_FAC" id="aaAttrTySelect_PRACSET_DENTFAC">Dental School Faculty</option>
      <option value="INDPEN_CONT" id="aaAttrTySelect_PRACSET_INDPENCONT">Independent Contractor</option>
      <option value="NO_PRAC" id="aaAttrTySelect_PRACSET_NOPRAC">Not Currently in Practice</option>
      <option value="OTHER" id="aaAttrTySelect_PRACSET_OTHER">Other
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="f47" size="20" maxlength="4000" value="">
</li>
```

Comment: The issue here is I cannot use the name to call the element.   This is a dynamic form so they have 12 choices to choose from at the begining and based on that choice the form will build itself.  Which means depending on which choice the name changes so in this case 46 and 47 work but if they make a different choice for the form then it could be 52 and 61.   That's the issue I am running up against the people who built this software decided not to use universal ID's for the for the fields making trying to do things extra difficult.

Comment: @KirkSturgulewski Is the ID for the "Other" option always `aaAttrTySelect_PRACSET_OTHER`? If so, you can just use `#aaAttrTySelect_PRACSET_OTHER` as the selector and get its parent element, which will be the `select`.

Comment: Thanks @Herohtar for the parent() idea I updated my code with that and also included a way to get the input tag too without using the name attribute too.

Comment: @AndrewLohr SO although yours is working when i run the snippet here it doesn't work on the site itself.   There has to be something going on with in the software this company created causing things to not function properly.  Ill keep playing and hoping i find a solution.